# Does MediaPlayer work in all API versions of android?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have a question about MediaPlayer. Does it work in android 7? Can it work with any API?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MediaPlayer` was [added in API Level 1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer). So, yes it will work on all API's.

Comment: Ohh ok. Thank you

Comment: Will sure do HB